# ¿Cómo desarrollo un programa en C con puntero que almacene 5 strings e imprima la dirección de memoria cuando el usuario elija alguno de ellos?

Tags: array, c, punteros

El siguiente programa obtiene la dirección de memoria de uno de los 5 nombres de animales introducidos por el usuario, esto es lo que llevo pero me marca error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x[5]={"León","Tigre","Jaguar","Chita","Puma"} ; //Queda claro que &x[0]es equivalente aX. Y, x[0]es equivalente a *x.
    int i; //Básicamente, &x[i]es equivalente a x+iy x[i]es equivalente a *(x+i).
    int *p;
  
    printf("Escribe el nombre de un animal: "); 
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
        printf("Dirección de memoria del valor:[%d] = %p\n", i, &x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Por empezar estás usando el tipo equivocado. Esos son literales de string. Lo correcto es guardarlos una *referencia* en un `char*` o  `char[]`.

```
// Este es un arreglo de punteros
const char* x[5]={"León","Tigre","Jaguar","Chita","Puma"};
```

El resto estaría bien. Para *seleccionar* un string en particular necesitas pedirle al usuario que lo ingrese y usar `strcmp` para saber si está en la lista.

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%19s", buffer);

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(buffer, x[i]) == 0) break;
}

// i ahora tiene la posición de la cadena.
// Si i llegó a 5 es porque no la encontró.
printf("Dirección de memoria del valor [%d]: %p\n", i, x[i]);
```

En lugar de `&x[i]` es solo `x[i]` porque es un arreglo de punteros.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y cómo le podría hacer para que solo me pida escribir un animal para que solo me muestre su dirección de memoria?